# Multiple widths with bevel modifier

Tags: bevel

I want to avoid to cut all necessary supporting loops into the mesh instead I'm searching a non-destructive solution for multiple widths using the bevel modifier.

I tested the various options (edge crease, angle, vertex groups) but none of them seem to work in this case.

How can I have a bigger beveled edge at the red areas but kepping the smaller ones?

[image]

Here is the file (Blend-Exchange won't upload me anything.)
https://www.sendspace.com/file/ne0eiw

This is what I want to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can set different bevel widths using **edge bevel weight**.

Set default edges at 0.5 bevel weight using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> - **Edge bevel weight** and "red"  edges at 1.0. When in modifier settings increase  **width** twice and set **limit method** as **weight**

[image]

You can also get an artifacts because of using subsurf after bevel. But, its easy to fix:

[image]

Comment: With this method I get pinched areas where the edges meet.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLIWs.jpg

Answer (score 1):

1. Select all with A
2. Deselect, with Shift RMB, the red edges
3. Make the remaining edges a vertex group and     use Bevel modifier > Vertex Group
4. Apply bevel
5. Repeat steps 3  and 4 for the red edges but different width.

Comment: This may work in very simple situations, in my case it creates massive artifacts. Even when I dissolve surrounding edges to let blender create Ngons.